# VLookup on different Excel files

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two different excel files.

```
(1)
    A       ....
    VAR     ....
    AA
    BGH
    AF
    BLA
    ...

(2)
    A     B
    SET   VAR
    1     BLA
    2     AA
    3     BGH
    7     AF
```

I would like to get information on sets for VAR in (1) different from BLA. So the dataset 1 should have

```
VAR ...  SET
AA         2
BGH        3
AF         7
BLA       
...
```

I have tried to use the following:

```
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("BLA",A1)),"", VLOOKUP(A1, here A column from the second file), here the column with SET)
```

but it is not working as it gives me #REF!.
Could you please to give me advice on how to use correctly VLOOKUP for this task? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` always search lookup value in first column for specified range, so use `INDEX`/`MATCH` instead:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("BLA",A2)),"",INDEX($F$2:$F$5,MATCH(A2,$G$2:$G$5,0)))
```

[image]